# Run SQL queries on jQuery link click

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to show a PHP function on an specific section (which has sql queries to fetch latest threads of that specific section) once when a link has been clicked.

For example the structure is something like this;

```
Section # 1  --- Link 1
Section # 2  --- Link 2
Section # 3  --- Link 3
```

When `Link 1` has been clicked it shows the `Latest Threads` of that `Section # 1` ... and if `Link 3` has been clicked `Latest Threads` of that `Section # 3` should be shown and so one.

I've tried using that PHP function inside the links but its running X number of sql queries for each section of my page. What I want is to make it so the sql query should be run AFTER when the link of that particular section has been clicked.

Is there any work around? Please pardon me, I've searched but nothing has been found satisfactory. :(

Please help!

Comment: Are the sections on same page or opens in new page? If same page, do you want the page to reload and load the threads of that section?

Comment: All sections are on single page, e.g. index.php, when the link has been clicked the sql query runs and shows the latest threads of that section on the same page, like jquery toggle and show latest threads.

Comment: If same page and you don't want page to reload, you need to use ajax. What it will do is -> it will load an external PHP file that contains all your queries to fetch the threads data and prints the result back into the page that called it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have to use ajax call than in the the ajax function callback to change the content the code should be something like that:

```
$('#Link1').on('click',function(){
var e=$(this);
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'myfile.php?id='+e.id,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function (data) {
      $('#mydiv').html(data);
    },
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       console.log(xhr.status);
       console.log(thrownError);
    }
    })
```

Also you have to have specific `id` tag for every link

In `myfile.php` you  should consider using the `$_GET['id']` and use it to load the data
this goes like:

```
$myid=isset($_GET['id']):$_GET['id']?die('the query is invalid!!');
// do some stuff considering the given id like mysql??
```

Answer (score 0):

//Function to call when link is clicked

```
function getSection(){

    //declare any vars you want here
    var variable1='variable1Content';
    var variable2='variable2Content';

    //Post some data to your php script without reloading the page
    $.post('getSection.php',{var1:variable1,var2:variable2},function(data){ 

        $("#targetDiv").empty().append(data);
    });
}
```

data is the response of php script (may be html code in this case)

var1 & var2 are the names you will find in $_POST vars in php script

"targetDiv" is the id of the target div in wich you will put your content.

Queries are done in php script.